# Change RAW photos data directly

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, photo, dng

I am using Python and RawPy to read and postprocess `*.dng` or `*.arw` RAW files.

But how do I modify the RAW's contents? I mean RawPy has `.raw_image_visible` Numpy matrix, which I can extract and modify, but can not reassign it back cause it is read-only.

Is there a way to make some changes to the RAW data and, for example, save the file back or perform a postprocess with a modified photo?

Comment: Almost no software writes RAW files, not Photoshop, not ImageMagick. Why do you want to do that? Once you have processed/changed it, it is no longer raw anyway - it's processed or cooked! Why do you want to do this exactly?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I understand. But due to my university science research, I have to make changes and after that just want to visualize it.

Comment: So save it as a nice, high-resolution 16-bit TIFF. Photoshop still allows you to process TIFF files as Raw, for example.